# How to swap string in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to make a function in C which will swap two string variables but something went wrong and the program crashes.

Please have a look at my code and tell me where I made a mistake:

```
#include <string.h>

void strswap(char name1[], char name2[])    // to swap two strings
{
    int lengthname1, lengthname2;
    lengthname1 = strlen(name1);
    lengthname2 = strlen(name2);
    char temporaryname1[100];
    char temporaryname2[100];
    int x;
    int y;
    // till just the declaration
    for (int x = 0; x < lengthname1; lengthname1++) {
        temporaryname1[x] = name1[x];
        name1[x] = ' ';
    }
    // copying the value of name1 in temporaryname1
    for (int y = 0; y < lengthname2; lengthname2++) {
        temporaryname2[x] = name2[x];
        name2[x] = ' ';
    }
    // copying the value of name2 in temporaryname2
    for (int x = 0; x < lengthname1; lengthname1++) {
        name1[x] = temporaryname2[x];
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < lengthname2; lengthname2++) {
        name2[x] = temporaryname1[x];
    }
}


#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[] = "hello";
    char name2[] = "hi";
    printf("before swapping: %s %s\n", name, name2);
    strswap(name, name2);
    printf("after swapping: %s %s\n", name, name2);
}
```

EDIT:- I have corrected the program and it is working properly. Soon my header file is going to work with some other modules. Thank you all for your help and especially to @Micheal

Comment: some examples at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-strings-in-c/

Comment: OT: `strswap` is not a good name (all names starting with `str` not followed by an undersore are reserved)

Comment: The for loops will run forever as neither x or y are incremented.

Comment: How would you swap two strings if they had different lengths?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many issues:

### First issue

The `x` variable is not initialized:

```
    int x; int y;  // first declaration of x

    // till just the declaration
    for(int x=0;x<lengthname1;lengthname1++)
    {//  ^ second declaration of x , local to the loop
        temporaryname1[x]=name1[x];
        name1[x]=' ';
    }

  // if you use x here it's the first x that has never been initialized
```

### Second issue

This:

```
for (x = 0; x<lengthname1; lengthname1++)
```

should be:

```
for (x = 0; x<lengthname1 + 1; x++)
```

Why `lengthname1 + 1` ? Because you need to copy the NUL char that terminates the string.

There are similar problems in your other `for` loops as well.

For example here you use `y` as loop variable, but in the loop you use `x`:

```
for (int y = 0; y<lengthname2 + 1; lengthname2++)
{
  name2[x] = temporaryname1[x];
```

### Third issue

In `main` you declare this:

```
char name[] = "hello";
char name2[] = "hi";
```

That is actually the same as

```
char name[6] = "hello";  // 5 chars for "hello" + 1 char for the terminating NUL
char name2[3] = "hi";    // 2 chars for "hi" + 1 char for the terminating NUL
```

Now even if your `strswap` is correct, you are trying to stuff the 6 bytes from the `name` array ("hello") into the 3 bytes array `name2`, there is not enough space in the `name2` array. This is undefined behaviour.

### And last but not least:

This is simply useless:

```
name1[x] = ' ';
```

### And finally

You should ask yourself why you need two temporary strings (`temporaryname1` and `temporaryname2`) in `strswap()` - one is enough.

Comment: @Micheal thanks so if i use "name[100] and name2[100]" then it will be correct

Comment: @SamratLuitel yes, but you need to correct the `strswap` function too.

Comment: @Micheal I corrected everything but it is still not working.Can i contact you somewhere.And one thing without using temporaryname1 and temporaryname2 how can i swap two string.And if i dont use name1[x]=' ' then some data will be remix. suppose one is hello and another is hi then while swapping one will be "hillo" and another will be hi only

Comment: @SamratLuitel look carefully at your code. Swapping is easy: 1. copy string1 to a temporary string, 2. copy string2 to string1, 3. copy the temporary string to string2

Comment: @Micheal anyway i have done i have forgot to copy '\0' character to a string so it was not working.

Comment: @SamratLuitel my corrected version of `strswap` has 22 lines (counting blank lines as well.)

Comment: @Micheal thank you. One question i will ask you out of topic.Where can i learn moving mouse in C. I mean i want to make a program start after clicking on some area

Comment: @SamratLuitel please ask another question on SO.

Comment: @Micheal I did and no answer at all. It become 4 week and my reputation got highly down

Answer (score 0):

```
void strswap(char ** name1, char ** name2)
{
    char * name1_1 = malloc(strlen(*name2) + 1);
    char * name2_1 = malloc(strlen(*name1) + 1);

    strncpy(name1_1, *name2, strlen(*name2) + 1);
    strncpy(name2_1, *name1, strlen(*name1) + 1);

    *name1 = name1_1;
    *name2 = name2_1;
}

int main()
{
    char * name="hello";
    char * name2="hi";
    printf("before swapping %s %s\n",name,name2);
    strswap(&name, &name2);
    printf("after swapping %s %s\n",name,name2);

    return 0;
}
```

Actually following is the safest way to swap two strings. In your cases, you were statically using strings of size 100 in size, which is not good and work in all case. Moreover, You tried to use ' ' instead of '\0' to mark end of string. String APIs uses '\0' to indicate that string has ended.

Comment: Using a magic number like 100 doesn't seems a good idea for a generic case, `malloc` and `free` can help.

Comment: @Mangu thank you but what was the error in my code. Can you tell me?

Comment: @d3l, Is the answer fine now ?

Comment: @ManguSinghRajpurohit now you are leaking memory, and you dont need `char**` here, `char*` is enough. And BTW `strncpy` is nasty, you can end up with a non NUL terminated string.

Comment: @Mangu can you explain it also. I am not well known with pointers

Comment: @ManguSinghRajpurohit it's even worse now. You aren't protecting against NULL pointer deferences, do not cache the results of the `strlen` functions and you don't check the return value of `malloc`…

Comment: you malloc but you do not free. And. You do not put strlen results in two vars, but you call strlen 4 times instead.